# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined using AngularJS, Rails 4 and Browserify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, browserify, browserify-rails

I am using AngularJS and Rails, and followed http://start.jcolemorrison.com/setting-up-an-angularjs-and-rails-4-1-project/ and several other tutorials to get a very simple "Hello World" example up and running on my desktop. The problem is, when I deploy it to a server, none of my code based on Angular works anymore. Instead, I get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` error in my console.

I realized that part of my problem is that the browser doesn't know what to do with the 'require' function calls, which makes sense so I installed Browserify using browserify-rails. However, it still does not work on the server like I would expect and I get the same error.

> Link to the live site: [Link](http://52.7.136.106/)

Here's my `application.html.erb` (simplified):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="/" />
  <title>ShibaInu</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body ng-app="shibaInu">
  <div class="container">1 + 2 = {{ 1 + 2 }}</div>

  <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

`index.html.erb`:

```html
<div ng-view=""></div>
```

`home.html.erb` (rendered inside the container):

```html
<h1>The Home View!</h1>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="thing in things">
    {{thing}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

`home.js`:

```js
angular.module('shibaInu')
    .controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.things = ['Angular', 'Rails 4.1', 'Working', 'Together!!'];
    });
```

`app.js`:

```js
angular
    .module('shibaInu', [
        'ngRoute',
        'templates'
    ]).config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
             });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

`application.js`

```js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular
//= require angular-route
//= require angular-resource
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require ng-app/app.js
//= require_tree ../templates
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Can you post your `application.js` manifest file?

Comment: @Zoran Thanks for the quick response! I've added it to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing several things wrong, but I'll try to summarize:

1. I am minifying JS on my server deployment like a good boy, but I was not writing minification-safe JS. See below for my fixed JS.
2. This wasn't specified in my original post, but I was not using the `angularjs-rails` gem like I thought I was. I added this to my project.
3. Related to 2 above, in my initial post I had used bower to install angularjs like the documentation recommends. For my solution, I took this out because it was just making things messy for my purposes.

New home.js:

```js
angular.module('shibaInu')
    .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.things = ['Angular', 'Rails 4.1', 'Working', 'Together!!'];
    }]);
```

New app.js:

```js
angular
    .module('shibaInu', [
        'ngRoute',
        'templates'
    ]).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
             });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
```